# iOS Google map SDK - Is possible to current location blue dot marker to red dot

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using iOS Google map SDK and I tried to change the current location blue color dot to red color dot. But I couldn't find the way.

Is it possible to change the current location blue color dot to custom (red dot) color?

If yes, please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have your tried custom marker ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to replace current location icon with custom marker. But custom marker is differ from current location icon. Here I need to customise the current location icon color.

Comment: Can you show me the current icon?

Comment: Need to change the current location blue colour dot marker to some other colour as like in iOS Uber application.

Comment: marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: .black)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Find the path as in the image]

If you are looking to change the current location icon, just find the GMSSprites-0-1x.png icons in the resources of google maps and replace them with your required icons.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Replacing icon image may be working. If I give pod update, that will get replaced.

Comment: Thanks this solution works for me. Just need to know if its allowed by Google. I tried reading document but unable to find any clue.

Answer (score 1):

just change the tint color.
`mapView.tintColor = UIColor.red`

Answer (score -1):

You should include MKMapViewDelegate. Call the method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

Change the annotation view to a custom view as you like. You can give any image.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

if (!pinView) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];   
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
       customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourLocationimage.png"];
    }
    else{
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Notyourlocationimage.png"];
    }
    return customPinView;

} else {

    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}

return pinView;
}
```

Comment: OP asked about Google Maps, NOT MapKit.